# how to match n number of attributes in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, loops, join

I have a database in which i store symptoms and paper id (in which paper what symptom is used) many symptom can be in one paper and many papers have one symptom.

Actually i am making a program in which user enters n number of symptoms and then program will return that paper who have all that symptoms.
now suppose i hard coded that user can enter only two symptoms so for this i can write this type of code e.g:

```
SELECT paper_id ,symptom_name FROM My_table
WHERE (symptom_name= "" AND symptom_name= "")
```

Now I want to know that what if I don't know how many symptoms user will enter
and if user enters n number of symptoms then my query will match all n symptoms and give me result.

Simply put this query is for two symptoms how can I make it work for n number of symptoms.

Comment: For the SQL in your question, you need to use `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: are you interested in AND of all the symptoms or OR?

Answer (score 4):

You can use an [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) expression:

```
SELECT paper_id ,symptom_name 
FROM My_table
WHERE symptom_name IN ("symptom1", "symptom2", "symptom3", "symptom4")
```

This will give papers that contain any of the symptoms. If you want papers that have **all** of the symptoms, you need a query like this:

```
SELECT paper_id
FROM My_table
WHERE symptom_name IN ("symptom1", "symptom2", "symptom3", "symptom4")
GROUP BY paper_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT symptom_name) = 4
```

Comment: Thanks for this but i do not know the number of symptoms so how can i dynamically enter n numbers of symptoms in this query for eg. in your query there are four symptoms but what if user enter 3 symptoms or five symptoms . I hope you can understand that how can i loop this symptoms part.

Comment: @Sameeruddin can you not generate the query on the fly and just make the `IN` expression the list of the symptoms the user enters?

Comment: @ZeshanKhan thanks for pointing that out. It wasn't 100% clear from the question what was required but on re-reading I can see that `AND` could be what is required. I've added an alternate query that will perform that function.

Comment: @Nick now it looks Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You need three different tables for this.

- `papers` contains fields `paper_id` (primary key), name, title, etc.
- `symptoms` contains fields `symptom_id` (primary key), name, etc.
- `paper_symptoms` contains its primary key, `paper_id`, and `symptom_id`.

Each paper has a single row in `papers`, and each symptom has a single row in `symptoms`.

If a paper with `paper_id` 1 is linked to two symptoms (with `symptom_id` values 6 and 7 for example) then the `paper_symptoms` table gets two rows:

```
paper_symptom_id  paper_id  symptom_id
(autogenerated)   1         6
(autogenerated)   1         7
```

Then, to query the symptom details for a given paper, you need a query like the following:

```
select s.*
from papers p
inner join paper_symptoms ps
on ps.paper_id = p.paper_id
inner join symptoms s
on s.symptom_id = ps.symptom_id
where p.paper_id = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the intersection of the query results for each symptom by using inner join as.

```
SELECT distinct paper_id
FROM My_table as t1
inner join My_table as t2
WHERE t1.symptom_name= "Symtom_1" and t2.symptom_name= "Symtom_2"
```

Comment: You need a condition for your `JOIN` otherwise it will be a cross join pairing each paper with every other paper.